# In what use case are classes more useful than a list?

Tags: python, class

I've been trying to learn classes and i struggle to see when they can become useful. In this example with employees i find using a well organized multi-dimensional list to be easier. 
I've provided examples of what i mean with a 2 sets of code that does the exact same thing using lists and classes.

I have tried watching many youtube tutorials on classes but i just can't seem to understand why a multi-dimensional list wouldn't do the job better.

```
class Employees():
    def __init__(self, First_Name, Last_Name, pay = "26000"):
        self.First_Name = First_Name
        self.Last_Name = Last_Name
        self.pay = pay
    def greeting(self):
        return "Hi, my name is "+self.First_Name+" "+self.Last_Name+" and I earn: "+self.pay
employee_1 = Employees("First_Name_1", "Last_Name_1", "30000")
employee_2 = Employees("First_Name_2", "Last_Name_2")
print(employee_1.greeting())
print(employee_2.greeting())



employee_list = []
def employees(employee_list, First_Name, Last_Name, pay = "26000"):
    employee_list += [[First_Name, Last_Name, pay, lambda: greeting(First_Name, Last_Name, pay)]]
def greeting(a, b, c):
    return "Hi, my name is "+a+" "+b+" and I earn: "+c
employees(employee_list, "First_Name_1", "Last_Name_1", "30000")
employees(employee_list, "First_Name_2", "Last_Name_2")
print(employee_list[0][3]())
print(employee_list[1][3]())
```

Comment: A class defines a type of an object. A list is a built-in container class.

Comment: In this case, you probably just want a `list` of `Employee` objects

Comment: `Class` == data + operations - lists are just data

Comment: If you just want to store employees' numbers and run some calculations on them, a list is fine. But once you write an app that will do meaningful stuff it is better to start thinking in classes, where every class has a certain task. I used to code everything as a procedure. In this case classes are not really essential. But once your app becomes complex and you need to be able to maintain it, you need to use classes.

Comment: @PatrickArtner not really. A `list` is an object of a class. It has operations (the list methods...)

Comment: take a look at this to get an idea how useful classes can be: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think he meant a list doesn't have any content-specific operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a class provides a convenient syntax for working with data, but it doesn't provide much you couldn't simulate. Consider a slightly different reworking of your list example:

```
# Employees.__init__
# Instead of named attributes, there are implied positions in a list
# 0 - first name
# 1 - last name
# 2 - salary
def make_employee(first, last, pay="26000"):
    return [first, last, pay]

# Employees.greeting
def greeting(employee):
    first, last, pay = employee
    return "Hi, my name is {} {} and I earn {}".format(first, last, pay)

# Call make_employee instead of Employees
employee1 = make_employee("First_Name_1", "Last_Name_1", "30000")
employee1 = make_employee("First_Name_2", "Last_Name_2")

# Pass employee "objects" to greeting
print(greeting(employee1))
print(greeting(employee2))
```

Support for inheritance aside, the only real difference here is that you pass an employee "object" explicitly to a function, rather than invoking a method on an object.

Inheritance and namespacing (multiple classes can have a method named `greeting` without them interfering with each other) are two big advantages to using classes, though.

Answer (score 2):

Classes are much, *much* more organized and useful than lists. For instance, classes have constructors, methods, attributes, magic methods, superclasses, etc. Classes are most useful when you have a lot of related functions and when you want to create more than one object. They can immensely help with organizing spaghetti code, especially when used with modules. Additionally, many libraries use classes rather than lists.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tenet of Object-Oriented Programming; you're encapsulating your data into classes as opposed to having them declared in a more procedural and ad-hoc fashion.

The *immediate* advantage is that the first code block is *way* more readable and its intentions are a lot clearer.  You have Employees and you know that you want to print the greetings of them.  With the second code block, you have a list which requires you to keep track of where each value is and it's not immediately apparent what `employee_list[0][3]` represents. It also becomes tough to refactor or fix if the order of your list changes for any reason.

Answer (score 0):

A class provides better readability and a better abstraction, i.e. you could inherit properties (variables/functions) for a 'dog' from class 'pet'.

Normally a class is better style as it can clean up 'spaghetti' code.

Comment: You can write spaghetti code with classes.  Classes don't change this.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are types and lists are already a built-in type with a constructor and methods (e.g. .sort). So the questions should be whether a type (or class) is sufficient for what you are doing or whether you want to have extra (different) behavior.

You can even extend the list type to your own version and change the behavior and add methods just like this and maintain all the ones that are already there:

```
class MyList(list):

   def my_method(self):
       pass
```

In a more general picture, whether you should use classes or not (functional style) is a matter of taste and philosophy. The big advantage of classes (maintaining state) can also be there biggest pitfall (side effects if not carefully crafted).